# Can you search multiple tables for a certain column or entity

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database but it contains about 100 tables. I am looking to find a certain column name within one of the tables but I don't know which table it is. Is there any way of righting a script where you can search for a specific column within that whole database without having to check each individual table within the database?

I am ideally searching for an entity within this column

Comment: Have a look at the `sys` objects; `sys.columns`, for example, lists details of all the columns in that database.

Comment: This does not help

Comment: Can you elaborate on *why* it doesn't help? `sys.columns` *is* the table you want to get the details of all of the columns in the database.